# Dynamic Machine Learning Model for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, tensorflow, machine-learning, coreml

I have an iOS app written in SWIFT. It gets user information and saves it in the database (Firebase). I want to use this data and then dynamically update the Machine Learning model created as the data updates to provide an improved prediction every time. Is there a way of doing this?

I know that I can create my trained model separately (e.g. using TensorFlow) and then use Core ML to import it into my app but how can I do this so the model keeps updating as new data comes in?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I don't know has or not (I think has) but I think you shouldn't do this. As you know, training a model take too much time, even with a `strong` computer. So if you do it with your iOS App, It can take hourly or daily. And user can't wait to see it

Comment: I wish to do this with very little data, e.g. 50 lines, and this should still be computationally efficient. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the model.

You cannot use Core ML for this as it does not support training. The Metal Performance Shaders framework in iOS 11.3 now supports training for neural network-based models. And you can always write your own training code.

If the model is something basic like a logistic regression, you can train it on the device and it won't take that long. If it's a deep learning model with many layers and you're training it on a lot of data, it might not be feasible to train on the device.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matthijs. I wish to build my model using collaborative filtering, however, I only have a small amount of data (using only about 50 rows). I am not aware of the Metal Performance Shaders and neural network-based models. Could there be an alternative to train the model in the cloud? And if I wish to test a model using logistic regression on the device, would you be able to guide me to some resources? Thanks a lot or your help

Comment: For collaborative filtering the easiest thing to do is to write it yourself with Swift and the matrix routines from Accelerate.framework.

Comment: Could you guide me to some resources on matrix routines in accelerate.framework?

Comment: Here is an old matrix type I wrote: https://github.com/hollance/Matrix and a conjugate gradient optimization routine I ported to Swift: https://gist.github.com/hollance/31da3d531385f822529d953a0566ffb0 -- both probably need fixes in order to compile with Swift 3 or 4.